# Why do you have to re-select a JQuery element from a collection?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of check-boxes on my page, each has a name attribute for its useful value.

I want to get a list of values for the checked items only. I can get a collection of elements like so...

```
var checkedItems = $(".checkbox:checked");
```

Now I want to create the list (string) so I create a loop...

```
var list = "";
for (var i = 0; i < checkedItems.length; i++) {
    list += $(checkedItems[i]).attr("name") + "\n";
}
```

This works and gives me my list. But the question is, why do I have to apply the JQuery object thingy i.e. `$(...)` to use the attr property?

if I had the following instead it would not work...

```
list += checkedItems[i].attr("name") + "\n";
```

But surely the array should be a collection of JQuery elements already? Why re-cast?

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dGeNR/) of the working example if anybody wants to try it

EDIT: Why does this work...

```
var item = $("#item");
var name = item.attr("name");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question is wrong, because

```
$(checkedItems[i].attr("name"))
```

should really be

```
$(checkedItems[i]).attr("name")
```

---

Besides that, you should really do it like this

```
var list = "";
checkedItems.each(function(){ list += this.name + '\n'; });
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/dGeNR/2/

---

The reason it would not work, is that when you access the elements in the jQuery object with `[]` you get back a direct reference to the DOM element, and not another jQuery object.

Comment: Forgetting the typo in my code (which everybody seems to want to correct without reading what I had wrote properly), you have answered the actual question, so thank you for that ;)

Answer (score 2):

`checkedItems[i]` is a raw DOM element, not a jQuery object.
To get a jQuery object for a given element in the set, call `checkedItems.eq(i)`.

You can do this more nicely by writing

```
var list = $(".checkbox:checked")
    .map(function() { return this.name; })
    .get()
    .join('\n');
```

Comment: fixed first example, sorry got it wrong when changing back after test

Answer (score 1):

Well the list-building code in your question doesn't work; it should be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < checkedItems.length; i++)
  list += $(checkedItems[i]).attr("name") + "\n"; // or just checkedItems[i].name
```

The ".attr()" function is just defined to return the attribute value for the first element in the list of matched elements.  It *could* have been designed to return an array (like the ".pluck()" function in the Prototype library), but it just doesn't work that way.

The ".css()" jQuery method is similar in that regard, as is ".val()".

Another way to do what you want is:

```
var list = checkedItems.map(function() {
  return this.name;
}).get().join('\n'); // thanks SLaks :-)
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume that what you actually do is this:

```
list += $(checkedItems[i]).attr("name") + "\n";
```

`checkedItems` is a jQuery selection. It contains references to the elements that it contains.  These elements can be manipulated by jQuery methods, or accessed directly with `checkedItems[n]`, where `n` is a 0-based index.

Those properties are not jQuery selections: they are the native DOM elements. If you want to use a jQuery method like `attr`, you need to create a new jQuery object, wrapping  that native object.

In this case, you can avoid that by using the [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) method, which gets a jQuery selection from an original selection by using a numeric key:

```
list += checkedItems.eq(i).attr('name') + "\n";
```

Even better in your case would be to use a combination of `map` and `get` and `Array.prototype.join`:

```
var list = checkedItems.map(function() {
    return this.name;
}).get().join('\n');
```

Comment: I see, so when a JQuery selector return a list, it is a list of DOM elements and not JQuery elements? Where as a JQuery selector that return one item (such as by id) would be a JQuery object and can have properties accessed directly?

Comment: @musefan No. Every jQuery selection, with one element in it or three hundred, is just an object with references to native DOM elements. `[i]` effectively "unwraps" the native DOM element from its jQuery wrapper.

Comment: I understand now, I didn't realise that accessing via `[i]` would cause this effect

Answer (score 0):

To be able to call jQuery functions, you need to wrap the content in `$()` or `jQuery()`.

I have fixed the example at http://jsfiddle.net/dGeNR/1/

You need to use `list += $(checkedItems[i]).attr("name") + "\n";`

Comment: I know that works, I meant to put that, just a typo when re-adding the $() bit after testing. See my edit for additional confusion on my part. This is not a question of my code not working, I want to know why I have to explicit set it again

Comment: -1... I had already found out that I needed to wrap the content. My question was why I need to do it to which you have not provided an answer. I only down-voted to counter what I believe to be an unjustified up-vote.